# Dependent inputs in Shiny application with R

Tags: r, shiny

Say I have a `shiny::sliderInput`:

```
...
sliderInput("input_1", "Title_1",
            min = 1, max = 10, value = 5)
...
```

Is it possible to reference `min`, `max`, and/or `value` in a different `sliderInput`? The use case for this is to make a second a input dependent on the first input. Something to the tune of the minimum of the second input can never be less than the value from `input_1`.

Something like (**this does not work**):

```
sliderInput("input_2", "Title_2",
             min = input_1$value, max = 10, value = input_1$value)
```

My hunch is this might be possible with `renderUI`, but not sure where or how to start?

Comment: In this case you should define a sliderinput in server.R not in ui.R

Comment: @AndriyTkachenko care to elaborate with an example/answer?

Comment: use `updateSliderInput`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example of `updateSliderInput` in shiny rmd

````
---
title: "Dependent Inputs"
runtime: shiny
output:
    html_document
---
```{r}
sliderInput("n", "n", min=0, max=100, value=1)
sliderInput("n2", "n2", min=0, max=100, value=1)

observe({
    updateSliderInput(session, "n", min=input$n2-1, max=input$n2+1, value=input$n2)
})
```
````

Answer (score 5):

This is an example of defining a widget in `server.R`:

```
library(shiny)
shiny::runApp(list(
  ui = fluidPage(
    numericInput("input_2", "select min value", value = 5),
    uiOutput("input_1")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$input_1 <- renderUI({
      sliderInput("input_1", "Title_1", min = input$input_2, max = 10, value = 5)
    })

  }
))
```

So it is reactive to changes in `ui.R`