# How to have items in selectInput use a common numericInput?

Tags: r, shiny

Sample script:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput("Select1","Name", c("Jack", "Daisy", "Mason")),
    numericInput("num_balls", "Number of Balls", value = NA, step = 1))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
    observeEvent(input$Select1,{
        updateNumericInput(session, 'num_balls', label = "Number of Balls", value = NA, step = 1)
    }) 
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have a selectInput with three names - I would like for them to share a common numericInput box and for the value to be different for each option, say for e.g. Jack gets 3 balls, Daisy gets 4 balls, Mason gets 5, however I don't know what the correct syntax would be for this to work. I would like to be able to use the values I give for each option from `Select1` in some other hypothetical part of the server script.

I've tried borrowing syntax for similar questions when searching for "dependent inputs" as my search expression, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30852816/dependent-inputs-in-shiny-application-with-r) for example, which recommend using some form of `observe_` or creating the UI in the server script through `renderUI()` but I'm still not sure of the best way to create a numericInput which can serve multiple options from another input. As you can see in the example when I try and assign a number to a person, say Jack, then go to Daisy or Mason, then go back to Jack, the figure I entered disappears. I know this is because the value in `updateNumericInput()` is always assigned to `NA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the values for the balls as a reactive value and then access these values with the selected name `input$Select1`. To correctly store the number of balls, you need a second observer that stores the value when it was changed:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("Select1","Name", c("Jack", "Daisy", "Mason")),
  numericInput("num_balls", "Number of Balls", value = NA, step = 1))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  number_of_balls <- reactiveValues()
  number_of_balls[["Jack"]] <- NA
  number_of_balls[["Daisy"]] <- NA
  number_of_balls[["Mason"]] <- NA
  
  observeEvent(input$num_balls, {
    number_of_balls[[input$Select1]] <- input$num_balls
  })
  observeEvent(input$Select1,{
    updateNumericInput(session, 'num_balls',
                       label = "Number of Balls",
                       value = number_of_balls[[input$Select1]], step = 1)
  }) 
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Note: you need to initialise the reactive values with `NA`, otherwise the first selected value is shown as the default for the other names when nothing has been selected yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can make changes to the selectInput cause the numericInput to update like so.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = "Select1",
              label = "Name",
              choices = c("Jack", "Daisy", "Mason"),
              selected = "Jack"),
  numericInput("num_balls", "Number of Balls", value = NA, step = 1))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  observeEvent(input$Select1,{
    
    if(input$Select1 == "Jack") {
      updateNumericInput(session, 'num_balls', label = "Number of Balls", value = 3, step = 1)  
    } else if(input$Select1 == "Daisy") {
      updateNumericInput(session, 'num_balls', label = "Number of Balls", value = 4, step = 1)  
    }  else if(input$Select1 == "Mason") {
      updateNumericInput(session, 'num_balls', label = "Number of Balls", value = 5, step = 1)  
    }
  }) 
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, the user can still modify the numeric input to other values if they use the numeric input box directly.